# mysqli select return no results

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm a beginner with PHP and I'm stucked with a simple request that returns nothing.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM order";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

 // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "something";
}

$conn->close();
```

This table is not empty.
I'm clueless...

Comment: Take a look at [this list at mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) for a list of reserved words in SQL. If you're using any of these, it has to be in ticks, take a look at [**When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Yes the name of my table was reserved. I will take a look at your files. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code looks alright.

To get errors that may have occured you can change the following:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(!$result) {
    die($conn->error);
}
echo "Result rows: "+ $result->num_rows;
```

You might find an error this way.

Comment: Thank you it says : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1".

Comment: Alright. "order" is a reserved keyword. you might want to try to put that in backticks. \`order\`

Comment: A reserved keyword !!! Damn !!! Thank you, thank you, thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It don't work with backticks but that's OK I will rename my table or something.

Comment: And I was wrong it work with backticks.

Comment: haha alright. Was also a little bit confused when you said it didn't work. I would appreciate if you could pick my answer as the solution. Thanks :]

Comment: `echo "Result rows: "+ $result->num_rows;` this is wrong, the `+` should be a dot. No idea why this answer was accepted. The real reason was that they used MySQL's reserved word `order` without using ticks around the table name.